# Solution for snmptrap required

Tags: snmp

This is the command which I have written:

```
c:/usr/bin> snmptrap -v 3 -l authPriv -u sam -a MD5 -A mysecretpass -x Des _x mypassphrase localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 3 0"
```

getting error as:

```
0: Missing type/value for variable
```

What is the solution? Something is missing in command line?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for SNMPv3 is significantly different from SNMPv1 ... and unfortunately, many of the options that `snmptrap` expects are very sensitive to position on the command line.  You're not the only one to be tripped up by this. :-)

You can try something more like the following:

```
snmptrap -v 3 -l authPriv -u sam -a MD5 -A mysecretpass -x des -X mypassphrase \
    127.0.0.1 69 coldStart .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 s trap
```

The option immediately following the OID is a type indicator (integer, unsigned, etc.), and "3" is not a valid specifier (see `man snmptrap`).  I've chosen `s` for string here, but you'll need to adapt your command to use the appropriate type for your purposes.